# Cannot build any Swift project at all due to strange error about MacOSX10.11.sdk

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm running macOS 10.12.3 with Xcode 8.3.

I cannot build any macOS Swift projects with it.

If I create a new Cocoa application Xcode project and set it to use Swift, when I try to compile it, I immediately get the following error in the "check dependencies" phase:

> error: There is no SDK with the name or path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk'

I have no idea what's going wrong!

The only clue I have is that earlier I created a symlink with the path `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk` that pointed to `MacOSX.sdk` in order to fix an issue where an older build of Qt that required an SDK with that path. However, deleting the symlink has no effect.

I can build Swift projects that targeting other platforms like iOS. Just not macOS.

Help!

Comment: do you still need to build that QT app?  If not, can you remove that symlink and if so, does the problem go away?

Comment: As mentioned in my post, I tried that and it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running this command then reopening the project
(Xcode uses xtools in the command line to build its projects)

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /path/to/file/
```

(by default the path is)`/Applications/Xcode.app/`

[look at this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2FQr.png)

[saw it here yesterday](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2339/_index.html)

Comment: While I had tried this before posting my question, what fixed it was using this command to switch to a different installation of Xcode and then switch back again.